# Neo4j 3.0.3 on Ubuntu: How do I load a .graphdb file to the web interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, import, neo4j

How do I load a .graphdb file (I created using `./neo4j-import ...`) into the web interface? I have used the `./neo4j` command to load the web interface, but I don't know how to access the database I created. The Windows version has the GUI to do this but the Linux version doesn't so I've never faced this problem.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy it into `$NEO4J_HOME/data/database`

and configure its name as selected database in `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`

```
dbms.active_database=test.db
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there an easy way to set the .graphdb path? Or will I always have to manually edit those files?